# A few issues related to GPU Rendering with Blender

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

As the title says, my system is pretty messed up after I tried to solve my own problems, so I'll just list them in hopes that you can solve them.

1. Ubuntu logs out to virtual terminal `tty1`
2. Blender doesn't see my GPU. I've installed plenty of packages from a number of NVidia sources, but Blender still doesn't recognise my ASUS GeForce GTX 650. I've tried using NVidia drivers, installed `nvidia-modprobe`, but nothing has worked.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does this command 'lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' does?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us) nvidia-361 is the driver for Nvidia GTX 650

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...In your case i am seeing it's not there but just to be on the safer side.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary. In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions

**Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs.**

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Blender still doesn't recognize my GPU. I did everything you said carefully, in order, but I still can't GPU Render.